# Access config properties with Python from Java Spring Cloud Config Server

Tags: java, python, spring

I have a repository containing config properties that a Java Spring Cloud Config Server accesses whenever another Java Spring App requests to pull the properties. I want to have the same concept, but with a Python app that pulls similar properties. I know there's Python Spring libraries out there, but I can't find an example of Python pulling these properties from a similar config server.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I have achieved this using `spring-config-client` library. I am sharing the code sample.

```
from spring_config.client import SpringConfigClient
from spring_config import ClientConfigurationBuilder

config = (
    ClientConfigurationBuilder()
    .app_name("dashboard-service-python11") #config file
    .address("http://localhost:3051")
    .build()
)

c = SpringConfigClient(config)
c.get_config()
print(c.get_config())
```

Comment: Yes this solves the problem. Does any one know how to use auto refresh in Python - meaning if properties are updated in SCC server how python program can fetch automatically? Is there any scheduler?